# How to create an HTML table with differing heights for cells in the same row?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create an HTML table with layout such as this:
[image: Table layout]

I have tried this, and a few similar things, but whatever I do, the layout ends up like a mess.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td rowspan="1">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">C</td>
        <td rowspan="2">D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As far as I understand your question, what you are trying to do is impossible. Can you share a JSFiddle?

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't what a table is for, unfortunately.  Is there any particular reason you want to use table markup?

Comment: School stuff. A friend is getting ready for an exam and I'm trying to help. This was apparently an assignment on the last years exam.

Comment: If you're trying to make a layout: use CSS, it has huge advantages in the long run and in this case it's probably also easier to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Yani: sure, this is what I was testing with: http://jsfiddle.net/mEV3h/

Comment: As the answers below indicate - rowspan is the way to gospan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually three rows in your illustration:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" height="40">A</td>
        <td rowspan="1" height="20">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `height` attributes can be adjusted of course, but if you don't have them, the second row will collapse to the smallest possible size.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mgKe9/

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. I actually did try using three rows, but had no idea how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that there are enough rows for your cells to span and that you specify the cells in the rights rows. This should help clear it up ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xkHs/)):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>Normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">D</td>        
        <td>Normal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>Normal</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The table that you are displaying in the question, is made like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> </td> // <-------------- Top left
        <td rowspan="2"> </td> // <-- Top right
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"> </td> // <-- Middle left
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td> // <-------------- Bottom right
    </tr>
</table>
```

You don't specific `<td>` tags that have already been "covered" by the `rowspan` or `colspan` of another `<td>`.

Comment: Blazemonger got the right answer first, but I'm leaving mine in, since the last comment is an important rule to know for spanning tables.